# Angular Component: Impossible to loop through an array of object with TypeScypt

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, for-loop, foreach

can any one please tell me why I can not loop through this array?
In ngOnInit, everything works fine. I got an array that I successfully display in the template.
But in ngAfterViewInit, console.log show the array but when looping through with "for of" or "forEach", nothing works.

```
import { JobsService } from '../jobs.service';
import {Job} from '../models/Job';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-job',
    templateUrl: 'job.component.html'
})

export class JobComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    title = 'Job';
    jobs: Job[] = [];
    InProcess = '';
    CurrentPartner = '';
    ShowProcess = false;
    sended = '';

    constructor(private jobsService: JobsService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.jobs = this.jobsService.getJobs();
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.jobs); // Show the array

      // Nothing happened when looping through the array
      this.jobs.forEach((oneJob) => {
        console.log(oneJob);
      });
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of the console in Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cUuu.png)

[image]

The content of the service:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Job} from './models/Job';

interface IJob {
  message: string;
  jobs: any[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class JobsService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  private REST_API_SERVER = 'http://localhost:8080/myband/api/getjobs.php';
  private REST_API_SERVER_SEND = 'http://localhost:8080/myband/api/sendjob.php';
  jobList: Job[] = [];
  errorMessage: any;
  message: string;

  static handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
      errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }

  public getJobs() {
    this.requestJobs().subscribe(
      iJob => {
        this.message = iJob.message;
        for (const job of iJob.jobs) {
          const oneJob: Job = new Job(job);
          this.jobList.push(oneJob);
        }
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = error as any
    );
    return this.jobList;
  }

  public requestJobs(): Observable<IJob> {
    return this.httpClient.get<IJob>(this.REST_API_SERVER).pipe(
       catchError(JobsService.handleError)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also print `this.jobs`.

Comment: You can see it by clicking the link to the screenshot.

Comment: Go to your `sources` tab in DevTools. `CTRL + P` and type the name of your file. Look if there is your code there. If it is not there, it is cache. Restart your webpack.

Comment: Thanks @MathiasGhenoAzzolini, I can see my code there. So I still have no idea where the problem come from.

Comment: can you apply a breakpoint on this.jobs.foreach and check what's the value in this.jobs?

Comment: Can you show us the code inside `getJobs()`? There is any error log? What is the result of `typeof this.jobs`? Try `Array.from(this.jobs)` please;

Comment: Hi @MathiasGhenoAzzolini, I just add the content of the service.

Comment: Your `getJobs` is async and you are not awaiting for the end of the subscribe async callback. I'm writing a complete answer for you, but the short answer: `return this.requestJobs()` in the `getJobs()` method and try to do what you are doing in your callback subscription inside your component;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I want to say to you is about isolation of responsibilities.

Your service must have just one job: provider one way to access your data; It means your logic inside `getJobs()` method could be done in your component.

```
export class JobsService {
    constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
    ) {}
    private REST_API_SERVER = 'http://localhost:8080/myband/api/getjobs.php';

    public requestJobs(): Observable<IJob> {
        return this.httpClient.get<IJob>(this.REST_API_SERVER);
    }
}
```

Now, you can handler your data in your component.

```
import { JobsService } from '../jobs.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-job',
    templateUrl: 'job.component.html'
})

export class JobComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    title = 'Job';
    jobs$;
    InProcess = '';
    CurrentPartner = '';
    ShowProcess = false;
    sended = '';

    constructor(private jobsService: JobsService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.jobs$ = this.jobsService.requestJobs();
    }



    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.jobs$
            .pipe(
                map(() => {}), // change your data here
                catchError(() => {}) // handler your error here;
            )
            .subscribe(
                () => {} // have access to your final data here. 
            );
    }
}
```

Things to know:

1. You can remove the `subscribe()` execution and use the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in your template;
2. The use of the operator map in `pipe()` is optional, you can handler your final data directly from your first callback `subscribe()`.
3. You can convert your `Observable` to `Promise` [using `toPromise()` method](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html) in one observable. Don't forgot `async / await` in your `ngAfterViewInit`.

Let me know if there is something I can help.

Comment: Hi @Mathias, Thanks for your help, I did what you suggested and end up with an error that I am trying to figure out. The error say **"Uncaught (in promise) undefined"**

Comment: Can you put your code in a codesandbox for me? This way I can have the big picture of the problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Object.keys(this.jobs).forEach(job => {
    console.log(this.jobs[job]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result is the same.

Comment: @WatiYé is this by any chance still an Observable? Did you remember to subscribe? Can we see the getJobs() function in the JobsService Please?

Comment: Happy I could help :)

Comment: it's actually not the problem. I tried synchronous http request and it worked fine that's why I thought you were right. I just add the content of my service I hope it can help you to help me :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign an iterator function with below part replacement by this code:

```
// Nothing happened when looping through the array
this.jobs.forEach(oneJob, function(value, key) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
```

**Usage of forEach in AngularJS:**

For documentation try to check [AngularJS forEach Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

***Syntax:***

> someIterable.forEach(object, iterator, [context])

Comment: Thanks @furkanayd, the problem is not the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below example

```
class Job {
    id: any;
    status: any;
    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.id = obj.id;
        this.status = obj.status;
    }
}

let arr = [
    {
        id: 1,
        status: "job"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        status: "job2"
    }
];

let newArr: any = [];

arr.forEach(a => {
    let obj: Job = new Job(a);
    newArr.push(obj);
})

console.log(newArr);

newArr.forEach((a: any) => {
    console.log(a);
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried a lot of different way to loop already, I think the problem is not the looping.

Comment: I have changed my commit please check and tell me it's working or not

Comment: The part you remove will break my code the Job model will create the object in the way that will be handle by the template. My problem is that the array of object (Job) got populated and display fine in the template but when I come to ngAfterViewInit, that array looks empty.

Comment: I have created a sample code for your problem please take a look and let me know the status... 
link:- https://cutt.ly/ce8jHwX
you can view the console log for status

Comment: Thanks @chirag, but I think that part already work I don't know why but the jobs show up in my template fine. The only problem that I trying to understand is why when I come back to ngAfterViewInit, that array some how become empty.